# Error with threads opening files

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I'm using C and pthread on a Linux machine, and I'm having trouble parallelizing a program.

I'm basically trying to take in a folder of data files, divide them into groups, each group handled by a thread, and run a function on each of the data file.

The way I'm doing this is I have a global char `**filename` variable, where filename[i] = filename of a data file. In the main function, I'll read in the filenames of all the data files (minus "." and "..") using scandir and put them in the filename variable. Then 4 (arbitrary number) threads are created each calling the Process function. In Process(), each thread only opens (using a `FILE *fin` declared in Process()) and works on a portion of the data files using a start_index and an end_index. For example, if there are 100 files, then each thread will handle `filename[0]` to `filename[24]`, `filename[25]` to `filename[49]`, `filename[50]` to `filename[74]` and `filename[75]` to `filename[99]` respectively. After they're done, there is a pthread_join in `main()` for all 4 threads.

I have checked that the filenames have been stored correctly, both in main() and Process(). However, I keep getting segmentation fault here, in Process():

```
for (i = start_index; i <= end_index ; i++)
   fin = fopen(filename[i], "rb"); <--- Seg fault
```

I don't really get why there should be an error since none of the threads are trying to open the same file.

Please advise.

Comment: please post the code where the file array is created...

Comment: Have you tried running it in gdb and seeing what `i` is when it segfaults?

Comment: And, what `filename[i]` is when it segfaults?

Comment: Beware of roundoff error and overrunning the filename[] array by up to 3 slots when `scandir` returns a non-multiple of 4.  Also, have you properly transferred all filename pointers from `scandir`'s namelist and **not freed** the namelist's members before all worker threads completed?

Comment: Try the code with a single thread first. Does it also segfault?

Comment: More code would help a lot... could be anything, need more code to digest

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here, you are probably setting `filename[i]` to `namelist[i]->d_name` and then calling `free(3)` on the `namelist[i]`. After this the pointer to file name is invalid. Or the `free(3)` happens in main thread and races with processing threads. You really need to [`strdup(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) each string and only release the memory after you are really done with it.

I of course might be wrong since code given does not show how the strings are allocated.

Answer (score 0):

What are the values of `start_index` and `end_index`, and hence of `i`, when the crash occurs?

If `i` is under control, the code should not crash - so that is the first thing I would check.

The show code fragment leaks file streams abominably because it overwrites `fin` on each iteration.  I assume that is an artefact of reducing the test code to a minimum rather than the actual behaviour of the (as yet not) working program.

Comment: There is a soft and hard limit on number of file handles a process can have which is usually 1024 on most Linux systems. Make sure you are not using more then that. ulimit will show you allowed number of files a single process can own. If you are opening more then allowed number of files change the limit and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with threads.

Are the threads executing the code before the filename is allocated?  Are your indexes correct?  If filename is coming from scandir...did you copy the filenames or just point to the value returned by scandir...because that value is no good long term.  Did you point filename[i] to a string on the stack of the function that calls scandir?

Try using strdup to set filename[i] and see if that works out.